# PHP access array element

Tags: php, arrays

At the moment I stuck on how to get access to the element.
Structure of array is like this:

```
{
"network":"BTC",
"event_type":"address-transactions",
 "addresses":{
  "3PvGLecQQMnm8oB2EqLbV94LFh7FLZpgJv":0
 },
"data":{},
"retry_count":0
}
```

How to get the value "3PvGLecQQMnm8oB2EqLbV94LFh7FLZpgJv". As you might already guess this is for some kind of callback. I'm totally confused on how to access the value since the lib of payment provider only returns the callback as an array.

When I use:

```
$payload['addresses'][0]
```

It says undefined index, using

```
dd($payload['addresses']);
```

returns:

```
array:1 [
"3PvGLecQQMnm8oB2EqLbV94LFh7FLZpgJv" => 0
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to json, you can access your data as an array with json_decode() : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php

The 2nd parameter is a boolean : When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
$json = '{
    "network":"BTC",
"event_type":"address-transactions",
 "addresses":{
        "3PvGLecQQMnm8oB2EqLbV94LFh7FLZpgJv":0
 },
"data":{
    },
"retry_count":0
}';

$test = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then :

```
foreach ($test["addresses"] as $key => $value) {
   echo sprintf("key: %s, value %s", $key, $value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[PHP code demo](https://eval.in/760616)

You can access a array value with some index defined to it, here

`3PvGLecQQMnm8oB2EqLbV94LFh7FLZpgJv` => `key`

`0` => `value`

and `3PvGLecQQMnm8oB2EqLbV94LFh7FLZpgJv` is the key which you want to find.

```
$string = '{
     "network":"BTC",
     "event_type":"address-transactions",
     "addresses":{
       "3PvGLecQQMnm8oB2EqLbV94LFh7FLZpgJv":0
     },
     "data":{},
     "retry_count":0
 }';
$array = json_decode($string, true);
echo key($array["addresses"]);
```